# How to use select within constraint or column level in create table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this table

```
ID | shares | value | percentage | total|
---------------------
1        2        60         0.222      270
2        4        120        0.444      270
3        3        90         0.333      270
```

I want to enter id and shares the remain column should be calculated automaticly where
value is `shares*30`
and percentage is value divide total (value/total)
and total is sum of all column value

I try computed columns but it does not work in total column

How can I do that?

Comment: You can use calculations in the select line. select id,shares,shares * 30 as value, etc... Post the query that you've tried for us, and you've got conflicting tags. Is this Microsoft SQL server, or MySQL (can't be both)?

Comment: You should not normally store data that can be calculated from data in the same record.

Comment: You can do the computation while inserting the data it self but how you are going to get the `total` value? it's confusing a bit.

Comment: its microsoft sql server and mr king king help me ,,, he is realy the #king

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare some columns as Computed columns however the `Total` column is different, we need to create some Trigger to update that column:

```
create table mytable(
             ID int primary key,
             Shares int,
             Value as Shares * 30,
             Percentage as cast(cast(Shares * 30 as decimal)*100/Total as decimal(4,2)),
             Total int)
go
--create the trigger to update the Total column when any change is made on Shares
create trigger mytrigger on mytable 
for update, insert
as 
if update(Shares) 
   update mytable 
   set Total = (select sum(Value) from mytable)
```

Insert some data to test:

```
insert into mytable(ID,Shares) values(1,2)
insert into mytable(ID,Shares) values(2,4)
insert into mytable(ID,Shares) values(3,3)
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/886df/2).

Comment: @MsaMan so there is still something wrong? I guess it's about the `Percentage`'s value, In my demo I converted it to the actual percentage by multiplying the decimal value with `100` but you may want to keep it in decimal form. Anyway if the answer's helpful, feel free to accept it :)

Comment: yes mr @king kinkg i modefy ur code to be like that >>>>>>>>           CREATE TABLE app
 (
 id_sh int NOT NULL,
name_sh varchar(50) not null,
 shares int  NULL,
 svalue  AS ([Shares]*(30)),
 percentage as cast(cast(Shares * 30 as decimal)/Total as decimal(15,15)),
 total int NULL,
 id_nationality int NOT NULL
 ) 
GO
--create the trigger to update the Total column when any change is made on Shares
create trigger mytrigger on app 
for update, insert
as 
if update(shares) 
   update app 
   set Total = (select sum(svalue) from app)
GO..... it help full with full acceptance thank u again

Comment: ,,, i will ask u with my pleasure again

Comment: @MsaMan ah, of course my answer just showed the idea, the demo was of course simpler than what should be done in your actual implementation. You can ask your questions in SO for many other experts to help (I'm not an expert anyway). However you should accept the answer (by clicking on the tick mark) if it's helpful. That at least encourages the answerers to answer more questions :)